Remove or offset Time of Day code from Motive FBX Export
I have a number of mocap files from Motive Optitrack. They were exported with Time of Day timecode. When I import them into Blender, the animation data is out of range of the timeline.
Is there a way of either removing the time of day code or moving all the mocap data tracks to frame zero?
